# Django : RelatedObjectDoesNotExist in view but works fine in Admin

Tags: python, django

I am getting a (RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: UserProfile has no site) error in one of my views yet I am able to perform all CRUD operations in the admin with out any errors.

```
django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: UserProfile has no site.
```

Excerpt from models.py

```
 class Sites(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
     active = models.NullBooleanField()
     created_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
     updated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
     logo_file_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
     logo_content_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
     logo_file_size = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
     logo_updated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
     logo_path = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
     account_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

     def __str__(self):
         site_str = 'id = {}, name = {}'.format(self.id, self.name)
         return site_str

     class Meta:
         managed = True
         db_table = 'sites'


 class UserProfile(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     site = models.ForeignKey(Sites)

     def __str__(self):
         user_profile_str = '{}: {}'.format(self.user.username, str(self.site))
         return user_profile_str
```

Excerpt form views.py

```
 @login_required
 def client_list(request):
     user_profile = UserProfile(user=request.user)
     print(user_profile.user.username)
     clients = Clients.objects.filter(site_rec=user_profile.site)
     return render(request, 'snapreport/clients/all_clients.html', {'clients': clients})
```

Comment: you forgot the Clients model

Comment: @user2021091 The complete source does include the Clients model, if I print(user_profile.site) before Querying the Clients model I get the same error a line earlier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line: `user_profile = UserProfile(user=request.user)` you're creating a new UserProfile for the user. And since you don't assign it a site, `user_profile.site` is `None` (or trying to access it throws `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist`).

You probably want:

```
user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
```

if the profile already exists (assuming that will have a `site`).